# What is the advantage of a move constructor over a copy constructor that takes a bool that says whether to copy or move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Why do we need a move constructor/assignment operator in C++ when we can just do this:

```
Foo(const Foo& x, bool copy = false) {
    if (copy) {
        // copy
    }
    else {
        // move
    }
}
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: the move constructor is faster.

Comment: But if there are no other advantages I think having a bool is simpler and you don't need to over complicate the language.

Comment: And how would you reliably move from a `Foo const&`?

Comment: @Praetorian what do you mean by reliably?

Comment: If Foo is a class that would actually benefit from moving, then moving from it is almost certainly going to modify it. Which is kind of difficult with that const qualifier.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley you can cast away the constness, which is also a cast, just like std::move, either way, it's all about casting.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 And that's exactly what I meant by *reliably*. Casting away constness might fail horribly if the object was truly `const` to begin with.

Comment: @Praetorian move constructors are used for temporaries, why would you have a const temporary? And how would it fail?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Seems we're running around in circles here. Given your proposed `move+copy` constructor, how do you restrict calls to it to temporaries only?

Comment: You can strip C++ down to plain C (or even assembly) if you are willing to take responsibility for doing everything by hand, correctly, every time. We C++ programmers like to let the compiler do the work for us.

Comment: @Praetorian, another question, is it still bad if we have a const object to begin with but we declare the private stuff that we want to move as mutable?

Comment: ...and take away the ability for the compiler to check that all the member functions that should actually be `const` don't accidentally modify these data members in the process?

Comment: Moreover, something like this would be a compatibility nightmare. It's not difficult to imagine existing C++03 code with a constructor `A(const A&, bool)` that would suddenly start getting called at all the unexpected places.

Comment: @T.C. but we can only call const functions on const objects, all the modifying functions wouldn't be marked as const.

Comment: Since you marked the fields as `mutable`, `const` functions can now modify them - and for all the compiler knows this is intended behavior rather than a programmer error.

Comment: @T.C. okay, you got me there. But we could restrict the behavior of mutable in a way that doesn't allow const functions to modify it, but that's already a language design issue.

Comment: One of the basic motivating use cases for `mutable` fields is to allow const member functions to modify them - e.g., to allow the result of logically const but expensive calculations to be lazily evaluated and cached.

Comment: 'But we could restrict the behavior of mutable in a way that doesn't allow const functions to modify it' - huh? `mutable` keyword is used to allow const memeber functions to modify object's internal state (i.e. members).

Comment: Thank you very much, guys, I have learned a lot from you all, also I messaged Stephan T Lavavej and asked him about this, I'll provide my own answer to this when he answers my email.

Comment: In addition to the issues others have mentioned, I generally try to avoid passing booleans to functions. It feels like a violation of the single responsibility principle when a function's behavior changes based on a flag passed into it. Not only that, but as an API user reading `Foo f(otherFoo, true)`, it's not immediately apparent what the `true` means here. There are other reasons not to pass boolean flags to functions, and [this article talks about javascript](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/08/hall-of-api-shame-boolean-trap.html), but the idea is certainly relevant to any language.

Comment: Can you also address the forwarding problem with this approach?  Also we need to address the non-special member move applications such as `push_back`.  I.e. sometimes you need to `push_back` an lvalue, and sometimes an `rvalue`.  A bool there too?  Users are going to want to do this for their own classes.  Convention: trailing bool always indicates copy/move?

Comment: @HowardHinnant I don't know what to say about forward really, I'm still learning C++11 and I haven't learned about forward yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move constructors are implicitly written for you (unless you block it).

Move constructors are called automatically for you in certain contexts, even if you have code written before they existed.

Move only types can exist with move constructors, and they block copy-actions with an error at compile time.

Marking something as 'please move from this' does not require a 2nd parameter, making perfect forwarding work.  Perfect forwarding also just works with rvalues. (perfect forwarding is imperfect, btw)

Move assignment won't work well well with your pattern.

The rvalue ref is useful in contexts outside of move/assign.

Honestly, comparing C++11 move and rvalue refs to your proposal is like asking why a Telsa is better than a tricycle with a broken wheel.  The broken trike is cheaper, I will grant it.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in C++ can represent anything. Files, threads, strings, 3d objects - all of this can be represented as instances of some class. Those objects may have a lot of internal data. Consider following example:

```
class Image
{
protected:
  Ubyte* _data;
  Size _size;
  PixelFormat _pixel_format;

public:
  Image()
  :  _data(nullptr)
  ,  _size(0,0)
  ,  _pixel_format(PixelFormat::Unknown)
  {
  }

  Image(Image&& source)
  :  _data(nullptr)
  ,  _size(0,0)
  ,  _pixel_format(PixelFormat::Unknown)
  {
    this->Swap(source);
  }

  Image(const Image& origin)
  :  _data(nullptr)
  ,  _size(0,0)
  ,  _pixel_format(PixelFormat::Unknown)
  {
    this->InitWithDeepCopyOf(origin);
  }

  void Swap(Image& other)
  {
    std::swap(this->_data, other._data);
    std::swap(this->_size, other._size);
    std::swap(this->_pixel_format, other._pixel_format);
  }
};
```

InitWithDeepCopyOf(const Image& img) initializes image with data stored in img, but it makes full copy of that data first (consider 32bpp image with Full-HD resolution - InitWithDeepCopyOf() will copy 8.3MB of data!).

In our program, we have another class:

```
class ImageHolder
{
protected:
  Image _image; //stores image by value

public:
  ImageHolder()
  {
  }

  ImageHolder(ImageHolder&& source)
  :  _image(std::move(source._image))
  {
  }

  ImageHolder(const ImageHolder& origin)
  :  _image(source._image)
  {
  }
};
```

In `ImageHolder`'s move ctor, we simple move construct `_image` member, so it will take default initialization of `Image` and 3 swaps. Copy constructor will need to copy construct `_image`, so all data will be duplicated.

Let's consider your solution with `bool` flag. It has 2 problems:

1) We cannot do it properly.

```
ImageHolder(const ImageHolder& origin, bool copy = true)
:  _image(source._image)
{
  if(copy)
    //...
  else
    //...
}
```

If `origin` is declared as const ImageHolder&, we cannot move it, because moving requires modification of source object - and we cannot modify const object.

If `origin` is declared as non-const ImageHolder&, we won't be able to do this:

```
ImageHolder new_holder(ImageHolder(image)); //parameter is a const reference
```

2) In contructor's body, members are already constructed.

When we reach this code:

```
if(copy)
  //...
else
  //...
```

`_image` is already constructed (more precisely: copy-constructed), which means, that you already duplicated all data (so there is no point in moving anything).

So, yes, it's all about performance. And if you think, you can waste CPU time on unnecessary copying of tons of megabytes of data... after all, it's only about performance.

Comment: I know what copying vs moving is, but if that object is const we can have the private members we want to move as mutable?

Comment: If you need to use `mutable` to properly implement copy/move constructors, than your design is wrong, invalid and very error-prone. That's why move constructors were introduced. They can give you huge performance boost  absolutely free, without any need for dirty tricks.

Comment: Because mutable members become modifiable at any point. As client of your class, I would probably have some problems with understanding why these objects are treated this way. Think about that: your idea is to make all move-constructible members `mutable`? You would probably have more occurrences of that keyword than all existing C++ apps together...

Comment: What? How can a client modify them? A client of a const object can only call functions marked as const. It can't modify anything by default.

Comment: 'Client of your class' is someone, who includes .h file with definition of your class and links against .obj/.lib/.dll file, that contains definition of its members. Making members mutable will impact seriously compiler's work - it will need to perform additional checks in every const function to see, if any modifications happened. This will kill optimization mechanism. And last thing is that constructors can be overloaded - you can easily add move constructor to existing code (it will be called whenever possible), but adding constructor with signature (const T&, bool) can be problematic.